# Show that a function is injective or surjective when the following condition holds.

Tags: functions

I would like to prove the following two statements.

1. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a function. If $f^{-1}$($f(A))= $$A$ for every $A\subset$ $X$, then $f$ is one-to-one (or injective).
2. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a function. If $B= $$f(f^{-1}(B))$ for every $B$ $\subset$ $Y$, then $f$ is onto (or surjective).

I proved the converse of each statement on my own, but could not prove the aforementioned parts. I would very much appreciate it if I could get some help.

Answer (score 1):

To show that $f$ is injective, let $f(y) =f(x)$.

By definition, given a set  $S \subset Y$, $f^{-1}(S) = \{ x \in X : f(x) \in S\}$

Then, if $A = \{ x \}$, we see that $f^{-1} (f(A))= f^{-1}(f(x)) = \{x\}$, so by definition of $f^{-1}$, since $f(y) = f(x) \in f(A), y \in f^{-1} (f(x)) = \{ x\}$, so $y=x$. This shows injectivity.

For surjectivity, let $y \in Y$. Then, if $B = \{y\}$, we know  that $\{ y \} = f(f^{-1} (y))$.

Suppose $f^{-1} (y) = \emptyset$. Then, $f(f^{-1}(y)) = \emptyset$, which is a contradiction. Hence, $f^{-1} (y)$ is non-empty, giving us the conclusion that there is $x$ such that $f(x) =y$. Hence, $f$ is surjective.

The converses of the statements are also easy.

---

Alternately, by contradiction :

Suppose  $f$ is not one-one. Then, there exist $x \neq y$ with $f(x) = f(y) =z$.  Then, $\{x,y\} \subsetneq f^{-1}(f(\{x\}))  \neq \{x\}$, a contradiction.

Suppose $f$ is not onto. Let $b$ be such that there is no $x$ with $f(x) = b$. Of course, $f^{-1}(b) = \emptyset$, so $f(f^{-1}(\{b\})) = \emptyset \neq \{b\}$, a contradiction.

For the converses :

Suppose $f$ is injective, then we want to show that $f^{-1}(f(A)) = A$ for all $A$. Let $x \in A$. Then, $x \in f^{-1}(f(x)) \subset f^{-1}(f(A))$, so $A \subset f^{-1}(f(A))$. Conversely, $y \in f^{-1}(f(A))$ implies that $z = f(y) \in f(A)$. If $y \in A^c$, then $f(y) \in f(A^c)$, which is disjoint from $f(A)$ since $A^c$ is disjoint from $A$, and this is not possible. So $y \in A$.

For surjectivity too, something similar can be done.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help. However, I have some parts I do not understand and I would appreciate it if you could spare some time for me. In the question, A is an arbitrary subset of X, but can I assume that A is a singleton set consisting of x? (the same question applies to an "arbitrary" subset B of Y which you assumed to be a singleton set consisting of y) Should I think of other possibilities such as a possibility that A (B respectively) is not a singleton set which includes other elements of X (Y respectively)? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: @TimLee Certainly, if $A$ is an arbitrary subset of $X$, then we can choose the subset consisting of just one element. The same applies for $B$ too. You could try to think about what happens if you include more than one element,that would be interesting. However, then I think the statement won't be true, in fact. The point is, if an element $y$ belongs to a singleton $\{x\}$, then $y=x$ must happen, whereas if you allow $A$ or $B$ to contain more than one element, this allows $y$ to have one of two values, which you cannot control. This is, I think, fatal to the argument.

Comment: In continuation (and conclusion), the fact you can choose $A,B$ to be singletons is *key* to the argument for the reason I said above. So, if you fix $A,B$ to have at least two elements, then I think you will find a counterexample to both the above propositions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind reply. Now I understand that letting A and B being singleton sets is key in this question. Thank you again so much for your help.

Comment: @TimLee You are welcome!